# Passing string instead of number to a  clojure program throws error

Tags: clojure

**java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e "(hello 1)"** is working with 1 as a parameter to hello function.
**java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e "(hello "vik")"** passing "vik' instead of number is throwing error.

Comment: What's the question? Have you tried the code you posted?

Comment: it should work, if I correctly remember... You don't need to eval `(use 'user)`

Comment: You're not escaping your double quotes on the command line. Also, what happened to the original "question"?

Comment: that was general form of same, just question is changed.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat __java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e "(hello \"vik\")"__ is not working

Comment: Ok, so what is in hello.clj, and what *exactly* is the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotation marks around vik. the Shell will interpret these before it starts java. java will see this:

```
 java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e "(hello "   vik   ")"
```

try

```
 java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e "(hello \"vik\")"
```

Comment: this is still giving error, __java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e '(hello "vik")'__ is working fine. (on windows)

Answer (score 0):

java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i "hello.clj" -e '(hello "vik")'
**for windows, since double quote is conflicting.**